# 3 Missiles in a Single Combat packet - how should this sticker be treated?

Tags: risk-legacy

3 Missiles in a Single Combat packet spoilers in this question:

> Does the mutant faction gain 1 troop after each turn in the Fallout Zone territory like it does in biohazard territories? We have a different opinion of “treat it like a biohazard” and the rule where mutant faction gains a army in biohazard scars.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

3 Missiles in a Single Combat packet spoilers:

> Mutants ignore the troop-loss effects of the Fallout Zone and treat it like a biohazard. Mutants gain a troop at the end of the turn in a biohazard, so they gain a troop at the end of the turn in the Fallout Zone.